# Binded list to a ComboBox with an inserted item from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create an uneditable combo box that is able to clear (null) the selected item.

I currently have a binded item source, but the first item is manually inserted which is designed to set the combox box to null.

I have it working when using a Static Resource.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Category}"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="8px" Content="(clear)"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource Categories}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (cbo.SelectedIndex == 0)
        cbo.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

But if I change it to a Binded list (storing an ID and showing a string), only the manually inserted item appears.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId}"
          SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="8px" Content="(clear)"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Categories}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

I found a solution online to be this, which does show the list and the manually inserted item

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId}"
          SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
          DisplayMemberPath="CategoryName"
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCollection" Source="{Binding Categories}"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="8px" Content="(clear)" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

But when the form is loaded, despite the binded CategoryId being assigned, the combo box is blank.  (It works after selecting an item.)

Edit:
Here's what a normal combo box does and what mine does with the added item.  Combo box does not show the selected item when the form is opened.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The category IDs are displayed in the drop-down, so what do you mean by _the combo box is blank_? Do you mean that the bound `CategoryId` property has a value that is initially not displayed as selected value?

Comment: When the form is loaded, CategoryId is set to a value.  A normal ComboBox correctly displays this value.  But my ComboxBox (with the added clear item), it doesn't display it.  However when I select an item from the ComboBox it does select and show the item.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Are you sure `Category` is already set, when the `ComboBox` is loaded? Do you set it anywhere later and forgot to raise `PropertyChanged`? Does it work if you replace `cbo.SelectedItem = null;` with `cbo.SelectedValue = null;`?

Comment: I tried changing it to SelectedValue, it didn't made a difference.

Comment: I have added a gif to show what it does.  The 2 comboboxes are identical apart from the how it implements the list.  PropertyChanged is raised anytime CategoryId is altered.

Comment: I have discovered that SelectedValue needs to be written after the item source.  So I have removed `SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId}"` and added `<ComboBox.SelectedValue><Binding Path="CategoryId"/></ComboBox.SelectedValue>` at the end